# Can't pass project.id from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller

I want to pass the current project's id to the tickets controller (creating a ticket for the project), which I try to do below. However, the way I do it below gives me the following link:

```
tickets/new?project_id=8
```

...when I just want it to be this way:

```
tickets/new
```

...even though I want the project_id to be accessible in the controller.

How can I do this? Just to clearify: I don't want the project_id to be a part of the URL, I just want to pass it (in some way) as a parameter to the controller.

**from view:**

```
<h1><%= @project.title %></h1> <-- the project's attributes is reachable here

<%= link_to "Create ticket", new_ticket_path(:project_id => @project.id), :class => "btn edit_button" %>
```

**tickets controller:**

```
1.    class TicketsController < ApplicationController
2.        def new
3.            @ticket = Ticket.new
4.            @id = params[:project_id]
5.
6.            @project = Project.find(@id)
7.        end
8.    end
```

The route that link_to points to looks like the following:

```
new_ticket GET    /tickets/new(.:format)            tickets#new
```

Comment: `new_ticket_path(:project_id => @project.id)`? you missed `@`?

Comment: I have tried that too with the same error. Though I suppose it should be with @ so I'll edit my Q.

Comment: what html `link_to` generates?

Comment: Then this tells me `params[:project_id]` is undefined. Try to hardcode an id: `Project.find(123)`. If this is the case, we need to see the request path, and your routes for this controller and `new_ticket_path`.

Comment: What does your route look like pointing to `TicketsController`?

Comment: Updated the question with the things you wanted to know...

Comment: Are you sure that your `link_to` looks in your sources same as in your question?

Comment: No, I just realized that. Will update the question...

Comment: Can you try restarting your Rails server just to rule that out? What you're posting here appears to be correct.

Comment: You can't get `project_id` from url such as `tickets/new`, which is GET route.

Comment: What you want isn't really a good idea ;)

Comment: No, I understand that but how do I actually pass it to the controller so I can use it there?

Comment: Only as a POST param. So you should create form and POST route for `tickets/new`

Answer (score 0):

If the tickets belong to the project, you might want to consider nesting resources.

Right now, your routes probably look like this:

```
resources :projects
resources :tickets
```

This generates routes like `/projects/new` and `/tickets/new`. What you can do instead is this:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tickets
end
```

This will give you routes like `/projects/8/tickets/new`. You link to a new ticket by doing `new_project_ticket_path(@project)`. The actual form of the route generate is: `/projects/:project_id/tickets/:id`. So params[:project_id] will give you the id of the project.